# JS code is intermittent in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

I've never seen the exception error in Chrome. The code below specifically views.contentView being undefined causes it to fail in Safari. Looks like it's a race condition. It never happens in Chrome.

```
$.when(this.promise).done(_.bind(function () {
  var views = this.getViews({
    model: this.Model
  });
  this.mobileView = views.contentView; // intermittent in Safari
}, this))
```

Any other ways to make it not produce the error in Safari? I was thinking of adding a setTimeout but that's not good.

Comment: You could simply check to see if `views.contentView` is defined in your scope

Comment: i did this if (views) { .... } and it worked but if it was still undefined, i won't get any renders which I'm worried